# Android Google Analytics connection to service failed

Tags: android, service, google-analytics, connection

I've implemented Google Analytics (V2) into my Android app. A while ago the code managed to send data to the profile (V2) succesfully. However now it refuses to connect to the service:

```
04-09 14:42:49.911: W/GAV2(8576): Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
04-09 14:42:49.921: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[main,5,main]: ExceptionReporter created, original handler is com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler
04-09 14:42:50.051: D/libEGL(8576): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-09 14:42:50.061: D/libEGL(8576): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-09 14:42:50.061: D/libEGL(8576): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-09 14:42:50.120: D/OpenGLRenderer(8576): Enabling debug mode 0
04-09 14:42:50.190: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8576): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-09 14:42:54.881: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
04-09 14:42:54.891: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned false for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
04-09 14:42:54.901: W/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
04-09 14:42:54.941: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
04-09 14:42:59.911: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
04-09 14:42:59.921: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: connect: bindService returned false for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
04-09 14:42:59.921: W/GAV2(8576): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
04-09 14:42:59.921: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: falling back to local store
04-09 14:42:59.971: V/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: dispatch running...
04-09 14:43:00.061: V/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: ...nothing to dispatch
04-09 14:43:00.061: I/GAV2(8576): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
04-09 14:43:52.951: D/dalvikvm(8576): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 4% free 7258K/7492K, paused 15ms+5ms, total 56ms
04-09 14:43:54.611: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8576): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

I'm pretty sure my code is sufficient since it managed to send data before. These are the steps I implemented (used the Android Google Analytics V2 docs):

manifest additions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

main activity additions:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {

    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

xml (analytics.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources>
  <!--tracking ID-->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-(copied from profile)-1</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

  <!--Enable debug tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">20</integer>
</resources>
```

I get the warnings at the very launch of the app. I've tried creating a new profile/account. I've tried using & #45; and & #8211; instead of the dashes. It's been 30+ hours since last data was received on the profile, since then the above logcat lines.

Any ideas how this is caused?

Comment: check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15014918/1168654

Comment: Check the answers posted here:

[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222468/android-google-analytics-connection-to-service-failed

Answer (score 2):

Might not to be your case but here it goes anyways.

I had analytics working fine in my app. I was using Eclipse and decided to switch to Intellij IDE. When I did it, the IDE showed me a typografic warning on the dash character of my analytics.xml file (regarding ga_trackingId). When I made the change (invisible to the human eye) the warning went away but analytics just stopped working.

Might be something with the encoding of the file, whatever, but I my case I had to **type** the dash character and not **paste** it (and also add a tools:ignore="TypographyDashes" in my file to get rid of the warning).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is important but my analytics.xml lives in "values" rather than in "xml" and it works fine.

Here is how it looks. Hope this helps.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-8158474-29</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">40</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

ga_debug make this to false and try once. probably you will get it.

```
<!--Enable debug tracking-->
<bool name="ga_debug">false</bool>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on the Google Analytics web UI that you are not actually receiving anything?

I have also the debug print that states no connectivity but my code still works (and I use EasyTracker as well). I am receiving events when I check it on the web UI. Is this your case as well? Unfortunately I don't know why the debug says it has no connection.