# Android : Tracking service component using google-analyticsV3

Tags: android, google-analytics

I made an application showing a window while calling in certain case, using service component.

The window contains info of callee.

I wanna know how to track this window.

Few buttons would be added with functions - ex : sending sms.

And I just wanna count how many times this window has been shown.

I found this question - [Android: can I use Google Analytics inside a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465793/android-can-i-use-google-analytics-inside-a-service)

But it seems it's about old version of GA.

And I failed to make that in my app.

(I tried :

```
public class view extends Service {
...

GoogleAnalytics mGA;
Tracker gat;
...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mGA = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(app);
    gat = mGA.getTracker("UA-my-account");
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    params.put("event", "test");
    gat.send(params); )
```

Let me know how to make tracker work in my app with GA V3.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Google is your friend https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: I already read that and it's about easytracker works on Activity that my application doesn't have. So I wanna clarify if any tracking object works on Service component. I tried some more codes and it's taking  time to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I made it.

```
GA = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(YourContext);
Tracker = GA.getTracker("Your UA-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
1. Tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("category","action","label",long type value).build());

2. Tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "SCREEN NAME");
Tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

now wait for a day for this to be shown.